# What's the difference between いえ and うち?

Tags: meaning

Apparently, according to my textbook, いえ can be 家　in Kanji. But うち can't.

Comment: 家 can be read both as いえ and うち, but うち tends to be written in hiragana to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

家 - Refers to a physical house or home (i.e., the building itself)

うち - Describes the meta-physical 'house' or 'home'